# flex state transition not played

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have created a component which has en edit mode when changing to this mode I want the component to play a transition, the state is changing but the transition is never played

```
public function LabelTextInputSkin2()
{
   super();
   states = defineStates();
   transitions = [defineTransitions()];
}

private function defineTransitions() : Transition
    {
        var parallel : Parallel = new Parallel();

        var rotate : Rotate3D = new Rotate3D();
        rotate.target = textInputEdit;
        rotate.angleXFrom = 90;
        rotate.angleXTo = 0;
        rotate.duration = 500;

        var rotateLabel : Rotate3D = new Rotate3D();
        rotateLabel.target = labelDisplay;
        rotateLabel.angleXFrom = 0;
        rotateLabel.angleXTo = -90;
        rotateLabel.duration = 500;

        parallel.addChild(rotate);
        parallel.addChild(rotateLabel);

        var transition : Transition = new Transition();
        transition.fromState = "normal";
        transition.toState = "editable";
        transition.effect = parallel;

        return transition;
    }
```